# How to get selected radio button from ToggleGroup

Tags: javafx, fxml

I an working on JavaFX 8 and `SceneBuilder`. I created some radio buttons in the FXML File and specified a `toggleGroup` name to a radio button list in that. So, now I want to get the `toggleGroup`'s selected radio button in my controller, do I need to make all the radio buttons again as fields in the controller, or just the `toggleGroup` object will get me the selected radio button (the text of that radio button only, not the button object).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
 @FXML
 ToggleGroup right; //I called it right in SceneBuilder.
```

later somewhere in method.

```
RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton) right.getSelectedToggle();
String toogleGroupValue = selectedRadioButton.getText();
```

Comment: Quick and simple!

Comment: Much simpler Jack, very nice!

Answer (score 19):

Let's say you have a toggle group and three radio buttons belonging to that group.

```
ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("RadioButton1");
rb1.setUserData("RadioButton1");
rb1.setToggleGroup(group);
rb1.setSelected(true);

RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton("RadioButton2");
rb2.setUserData("RadioButton2");
rb2.setToggleGroup(group);

RadioButton rb3 = new RadioButton("RadioButton3");
rb3.setUserData("RadioButton3");
rb3.setToggleGroup(group);
```

When you select a radio button from that toggle group, the following `changed(...)` method will be called.

```
group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>(){
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {

         if (group.getSelectedToggle() != null) {

             System.out.println(group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString());
             // Do something here with the userData of newly selected radioButton

         }

     } 
});
```

Comment: I was asking if I am reqd. to make the 3 RadioButtons again in the controller (after having made them in FXML), or I can make just the ToggleGroup object only and access the selected button somehow.

Comment: @Rounaq_intel, try just adding the togglegroup to the controller and adding the listener in above answer.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

This was never properly or thoroughly answered, so I thought I would post the solution I got.

When you create radio buttons in `SceneBuilder`, then ALSO use `SceneBuilder` to assign them to a group. The way you access that group via the Controller is to first create a variable of type `ToggleGroup` in the Controller and name it the exact same name as the one you created in `SceneBuilder`. Then you can use it.  Here is a pseudocode example of how I did it:

```
// your imports
public class Controller
{
    @FXML ToggleGroup   myGroup; //I called it myGroup in SceneBuilder as well.

    public void myGroupAction(ActionEvent action)
    {
      System.out.println("Toggled: " + myGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString());
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
      //whatever initialize code you have here
    }
}
```

Although the text returned from the `getUserData` property is lengthy. Here is a way to get just the name of the Radio Button:

```
myGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>()
    {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle t, Toggle t1)
        {
        RadioButton chk = (RadioButton)t1.getToggleGroup().getSelectedToggle(); // Cast object to radio button
        System.out.println("Selected Radio Button - "+chk.getText());
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps someone down the road ...

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyControler {
    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup myToggleGroup;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        //the simplest way to print current value (text of the selected radio button)
        System.out.format("Selected Radio Button: " + ((RadioButton)myToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle()).getText());

        //register on change event
        myToggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable, Toggle oldToggle, Toggle newToggle)
            {
                //print new selected value after change
                System.out.println("Selected Radio Button: " + ((RadioButton)newToggle).getText());
            }
        });
    }

    //sample method to set radio button (unselect all if group don't contain value)
    private void setRadioButtons(ToggleGroup toggleGroup, String value) {
        for (Toggle t : toggleGroup.getToggles()) 
            t.setSelected(((RadioButton) t).getText().equals(value));
    }

    //sample method to set radio button (select existing value or do nothing)
    private void setRadioButton(ToggleGroup toggleGroup, String value) {
        for (Toggle t : toggleGroup.getToggles()) 
            if(((RadioButton) t).getText().equals(value)) 
                t.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I got is:

`ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();`

Then set toggleGroup to the radio button; let's say r1 and r2

```
r1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

r2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

toggleGroup.setUserData(toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().toString());
```

To print the data of RadioButton:

```
System.out.println("Selected Radio Button is " + toggleGroup.getUserData().toString());
```