# How do I use radio buttons in Java?

Tags: java, javafx

so I want to make a set of radio buttons. If I press a radio button a new set of text fields will pop up. What piece of code do I use to achieve this? I am using Java by the way and just want to use JavaFX to achieve my objective. I've heard of using a certain command of showVisible but I'm not sure if that will work?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424915/how-to-get-selected-radio-button-from-togglegroup), please before asking try to google your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As I got the impression that you are new to javafx, why not following a few tutorials on it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm new just taking a intro to java course at college

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio button:

```
ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton("RadioButton1");
rb1.setUserData("RadioButton1");
rb1.setToggleGroup(group);
rb1.setSelected(true);
```

and when you want to change the text do this:

```
group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>(){
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {

     if (group.getSelectedToggle() != null) {


         // Do something here with the radioButton

     }

 } 
 });
```

Comment: Better make sure to add the listener before selecting the `RadioButton`, since otherwise this could lead to unexpected behavior. (If a user selects another toggle and then selects the original toggle again the effects of the code in the listener are only applied the second time...)

Comment: At this point once the radio button is selected, all you have to do is set the visibility of the textfields to true;